# Так будет лучше, так будет лучше, ведь жизнь сама, ведь жизнь сама(,) счастливый случай, счастливый случай

Tags: запятые

Нужна эта запятая из песни Боярского «Поверь в себя»?

> Так будет лучше, так будет лучше, ведь жизнь сама, ведь жизнь сама(,) счастливый случай, счастливый случай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что здесь нужно поставить не запятую, а **тире** (*жизнь* — подлежащее, *случай* — сказуемое):

*Поверь в себя, поверь в себя,

Так будет лучше, так будет лучше.

Ведь жизнь сама, ведь жизнь сама **—**

Счастливый случай, счастливый случай.*
Н. Шемятенкова

> **1.** Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа: ***Одиночество** в творчестве — тяжёлая **штука*** (Ч.)...

*Жизнь сама по себе — бессмысленный процесс* (Э. Лимонов).
*Ведь сама жизнь порой — ложь и обман* (В. Султанлы).

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)
[Поверь в себя](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/fel%27zman/stranizi/Pover%27vsebya.html)

Comment: Но *сама* — это ведь как обстоятельство.

Comment: Ну... Мне кажется, что "сама" здесь не имеет наречного значения, тут — подчеркивание. **II** — *Автор изображает саму жизнь и такой, какая она есть*. (https://gufo.me/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC)

Comment: "Жизнь сама по себе сплошной риск, а путешествие в горах — это вообще на грани выживаемости".  Почему нет тире?  Все в этой теме сложнее, чем кажется.

Comment: Отвечу словами Розенталя: Примечание. **Обычно** тире не ставится: <...> 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, **иногда — наречие**, союз, частица (обычно, иногда... — много "допустимостей"). В Вашем предложении сочетание "сама по себе" выступает в роли наречия, поэтому тире автор и не поставил. А вот у Лимонова в такой же ситуации тире имеется (см. пример). P. S. В песне еще и повторы, думаю, влияют: надо, надо разделить предложение на смысловые части. И тире тут самый подходящий знак. Прямо просится.

Comment: На самом деле на каждое "тире ставится" можно подобрать "тире не ставится", просто изменив структуру предложения. Например: Условно говоря, жизнь сплошной риск, а путешествие в горах — это вообще на грани выживаемости.  В каждом конкретном случае своя ситуация, а не "такая же".  От расстановки ударений никуда не уйти, как бы ни хотелось. А у Розенталя все "обычно", базовый вариант. Он хорошо страхуется)

Comment: Думаю, что в лингвистике надо быть честным хотя бы самому с собой. Действительная причина постановки тире в данном случае – это структура предложения и стихотворный ритм, задающий паузу, а все остальное софистика. Потому что всегда лучше сослаться на правило, на примеры и т.д.